# how to detect incoming data to broswer using javascript

Tags: javascript

currently i'm developing a `Firefox` extension to automatically  reply facebook message automatically .only for messages which has genaral pattern like `(how are u?)`.but i can't detect when a message is recieved.all i need is detect msg immediately.i have see those data came to browser from http request or something like that[i'm not sure but i have seen in console].can i detect a incoming msg without manipulating dom?it's harder to find by detect dom changes ..i think question is clear .another example for this is think i want to play a sound when i received notification from stackoverflow  .so i can do this by manipulating dom but it's not efficient and so bad way.is there another way??

this is how data come to browser [what i see in console when message,notification...come to browser]

[image]